# Trying to Connect to SQL Server with DSN for Classic ASP Connection

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I currently have a connection page that connects to access db. I have been trying to figure how to get it to connect to SQL instead. The code is also written in VBScript. I tried different combinations but I have had no luck so far.

connection page

```
 <%
   Dim objConn
   Session.Timeout=15
   Set objConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   objConn.ConnectionString="DSN=STAFFING"
   objConn.Open 
   %>
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
   <%
   Dim objConn
   Session.Timeout=15
   Set objConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   objConn.ConnectionString="DSN=servername;Initial Catalog=staffing;Integrated Security=True"
   objConn.Open 
   %>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Did you create the DSN called "servername" on the web server?  Or are you trying to connect directly to SQL Server using that connection string?  The code looks fine, I suspect your issue is between the (non?)existing DSN and the connection string.  This is a good resource for connection string syntax:  http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: I put the name servername in replace of the real servername so as not to show it on public site. I am getting error Microsoft OLE DB Service Components error '80040e21'

Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

/STAFFINGtest/CONNECTIONSTRING/CONNECTIONSTRING.ASP, line 6

Comment: oh I need to create a DSN on the server duh forgot to do that

Comment: Ok I did add the dsn but still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to post the error message

Comment: @Donny, make sure you have created SYSTEM DNS not USER DNS

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using a DSN to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: the code is written in classic asp and it was currently using DSN for access . I was just switching it to sql from access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue with help from squillman and users on stackoverflow. one I did not create DSN on the server. Second I needed to add the username and password on the connection page and when creating the System DSN on the server.

```
<%
   Dim objConn
   Session.Timeout=15
   Set objConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   objConn.ConnectionString="DSN=servername;Uid=Username;Pwd=Password"
   objConn.Open 
   %>
```